# How can I suppress a ListView from displaying when content when empty

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I have an object that contains an IEnumerable called ValidPhones as a property. When I bind it to a WPF ListView like such:

```
<ListView DataContext="{Binding ValidPhones}">
  <TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
      <MultiBinding StringFormat='{}{0}: {1}'>
        <Binding Path='Type' />
        <Binding Path='PhoneNumber' />
      </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
  </TextBlock>
</ListView>
```

It still ends up displaying the ": " in the UI even when the Enumerable is empty. Is there a simple way to suppress that from happening?

Comment: Are you sure it's empty? I don't see this behavior with your code.

Comment: Thanks that was in fact it. Someone else was prepopulating lists that I believed to be empty. I just stupidly forgot to debug and check that it was in fact empty.

Answer (score 0):

What backend language are you using with wpf? I'm fairly sure it's either c# or VB.NET. I'm no expert, but I'm pretty sure you can access things like ListViews from code.

Comment: We are using C#, but doing it in code is not a viable option. The piece of xaml in question is being loaded out of a database and parsed at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: sorry...I missed the comment at the top. Please mark your threads as closed when you solve the problem so silly people like me don't post useless answers.

Sure! In fact, there are a few options for you to consider.

Option 1: You can always change the visibility of your control to "collapsed" when the list is empty, which will keep your application from rendering it in the xaml. This can be done from your C# code or your xaml. this is a viable solution, but be careful that you don't have other controls that are dependant upon the location of the listview, because setting the visibility to "collapsed" will tell your applicaitonPage not to render the listview at all, which can mess with your layout.

Option 2: You can set up an "IsEmpty" attribute for your iEnumerable, and then bind that attribute to the textblock's text property. If you do it this way then you will need a converter that can return either a blank string or the properly formatted one depending on the value of IEnumerable. This opiton is slightly more complicated, but it has the benefit of leaving your listview alone so that the other controls don't move around.

Please let me know if you need help with either of these options, or if they need clarificaiton :)